# Datatables: Select table length look incorrect for IE11

Tags: datatables, internet-explorer-11

I use datatables plugin (https://datatables.net/) and only in IE11 this select looks incorrect for all tables. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: What is your exact question? See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show your HTML markup and DataTables related code.